# How to add SSML tags to HTML page

Tags: html, google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech, ssml

I have some knowledge about SSML speech Synthesis Marku Language. I am using google cloud text to speech API, that converts text to speech for an given text/SSML as input.

Now I am trying to get speech of an blogs which is really an HTML. Should I add SSML voice tags to HTML get an audio pf an blog?
Kindly provide an reference to add SSML tags to HTML

Comment: Although this seems to be interesting I don't really understand the use case. Can you add some code examples and results? Or at least pseudocode to help us understand what is on your mind?

Comment: This is perhaps relevant: [Specification for Spoken Presentation in HTML (W3C Working Draft 23 September 2021)](https://www.w3.org/TR/spoken-html/).